# help interpreting lspci output re: suspend issues with 2016 MacBook Pro

Tags: suspend, macbook-pro, devices, lspci

I'm trying to determine why my MacBook Pro (late 2016, MacBookPro13,1) has issues (multiple) when being suspended / waking up. This is one symptom I'm observing.

Using dmesg, I see these messages after suspending:

```
[  820.490170] pcieport 0000:05:00.0: Unable to change power state from D0 to D3hot, device inaccessible
[  820.490171] pcieport 0000:05:02.0: Unable to change power state from D0 to D3hot, device inaccessible
[  820.491980] pcieport 0000:04:00.0: Unable to change power state from D0 to D3hot, device inaccessible
```

and eventually

```
[  820.553988] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: Unable to change power state from D3hot to D0, device inaccessible
```

Here is what lspci shows me before the suspend. The first output uses -nn, the second -t -nn.

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [8086:1904] (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Iris Graphics 540 [8086:1926] (rev 0a)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [8086:9d2f] (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 [8086:9d60] (rev 21)
00:15.2 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #2 [8086:9d62] (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 [8086:9d3a] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 [8086:9d10] (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 [8086:9d14] (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 [8086:9d18] (rev f1)
00:1d.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #10 [8086:9d19] (rev f1)
00:1e.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO UART Controller #0 [8086:9d27] (rev 21)
00:1e.3 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO SPI Controller #1 [8086:9d2a] (rev 21)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller [8086:9d48] (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller [0580]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC [8086:9d21] (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [8086:9d70] (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus [8086:9d23] (rev 21)
01:00.0 Mass storage controller [0180]: Apple Inc. S3X NVMe Controller [106b:2003] (rev 11)
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4350 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a3] (rev 05)
03:00.0 Multimedia controller [0480]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries 720p FaceTime HD Camera [14e4:1570]
04:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation DSL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Alpine Ridge 4C 2015] [8086:1578] (rev 02)
05:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] [8086:15d3] (rev 02)
05:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] [8086:15d3] (rev 02)
05:02.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] [8086:15d3] (rev 02)
05:04.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] [8086:15d3] (rev 02)
06:00.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 NHI (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] [8086:15d2] (rev 02)
07:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] [8086:15d4] (rev 02)
```

```
-[0000:00]-+-00.0  Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [8086:1904]
           +-02.0  Intel Corporation Iris Graphics 540 [8086:1926]
           +-14.0  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [8086:9d2f]
           +-15.0  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 [8086:9d60]
           +-15.2  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #2 [8086:9d62]
           +-16.0  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 [8086:9d3a]
           +-1c.0-[01]----00.0  Apple Inc. S3X NVMe Controller [106b:2003]
           +-1c.4-[04-79]----00.0-[05-79]--+-00.0-[06]----00.0  Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 NHI (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] [8086:15d2]
           |                               +-01.0-[08-40]--
           |                               +-02.0-[07]----00.0  Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] [8086:15d4]
           |                               \-04.0-[41-79]--
           +-1d.0-[02]----00.0  Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4350 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a3]
           +-1d.1-[03]----00.0  Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries 720p FaceTime HD Camera [14e4:1570]
           +-1e.0  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO UART Controller #0 [8086:9d27]
           +-1e.3  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO SPI Controller #1 [8086:9d2a]
           +-1f.0  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller [8086:9d48]
           +-1f.2  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC [8086:9d21]
           +-1f.3  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [8086:9d70]
           \-1f.4  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus [8086:9d23]
```

I notice that the [8086:1578] and [8086:15d3] devices (the ones that complain in the dmesg log) do not show up in this tree structure.

Finally, after resume, the tree structure is completely different.

```
-+-[0000:07]---00.0  Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] [8086:15d4]
 +-[0000:06]---00.0  Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 NHI (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] [8086:15d2]
 +-[0000:05]-+-00.0  Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] [8086:15d3]
 |           +-01.0  Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] [8086:15d3]
 |           +-02.0  Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] [8086:15d3]
 |           \-04.0  Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] [8086:15d3]
 +-[0000:04]---00.0  Intel Corporation DSL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Alpine Ridge 4C 2015] [8086:1578]
 \-[0000:00]-+-00.0  Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [8086:1904]
             +-02.0  Intel Corporation Iris Graphics 540 [8086:1926]
             +-14.0  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [8086:9d2f]
             +-15.0  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 [8086:9d60]
             +-15.2  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #2 [8086:9d62]
             +-16.0  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 [8086:9d3a]
             +-1c.0-[01]----00.0  Apple Inc. S3X NVMe Controller [106b:2003]
             +-1c.4  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 [8086:9d14]
             +-1d.0-[02]----00.0  Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4350 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a3]
             +-1d.1-[03]----00.0  Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries 720p FaceTime HD Camera [14e4:1570]
             +-1e.0  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO UART Controller #0 [8086:9d27]
             +-1e.3  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO SPI Controller #1 [8086:9d2a]
             +-1f.0  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller [8086:9d48]
             +-1f.2  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC [8086:9d21]
             +-1f.3  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [8086:9d70]
             \-1f.4  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus [8086:9d23]
```

My suspicion here is that something is wrong with the device hierarchy setup vis-a-vis the order to deal with the devices during suspend. But I know enough that I don't know enough about this to figure it out myself.

Any pointers, hints, "get a clue" clues, etc. would be appreciated. Thanks!